# Error: The requested URL /login was not found on this server. (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, redhat

```
PHP 7.4.9
Laravel 7.20.0
Appache 2.4.6
RedHat 7
```

I deployed my laravel project on the server and I am receiving the below error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
```

I tried almost all solutions that i found online.
The problem stayed the same.
mod_rewrite is enabled.
I added multiple line to httpd.conf and fix DocumentRoot

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/chatbot/public"

<Directory "/var/www/html/chatbot/public">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

/var/www/html/chatbot/public/htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note that when i try to link the DocumentRoot to a new laravel project, it works fine, but for the deployed code its not working(receiving the above error).

[image]

Public folder:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a other custom url to your routes and check if that works? Did you add the authentication package to laravel for login etc?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is that file really called `htaccess` without a leading dot?

Comment: @NicoShultz ohhh, i tried other custom url(simple html file) and it works fine. and for login packages, i deployed the code from the localhost, and localy it was working fine, what does that mean?

Comment: can u check `/login` page not found error is `apche2` 404 or `Larave`l 404

Comment: @KamleshPaul how can i check ? btw i am receiving this error only for login page, i dont know why.

Comment: u can send me screen shot

Comment: @KamleshPaul i added a screen shot

Comment: @JosephNehme this is server error it means your server trying to handel it but not resolved

Comment: @KamleshPaul why i am facing this ? noting that the application locally was running very well

Comment: do u have `login` folder inside laravel `public` dir .? can u check this

Comment: @KamleshPaul I added a picture of my public dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220418/discussion-between-joseph-nehme-and-kamlesh-paul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was so silly.
i Changed the folder name from:

```
htaccess
```

To:

```
.htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel doc:

> If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your
> Apache installation, try this alternative:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

[read more](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#pretty-urls)

after this apply and restart your apache server

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried it and still have the same error